# Nuxt.js 3 meta tag

Tags: vuejs3, meta-tags, nuxtjs3

In Nuxt 3, I fill my meta tags with the data coming from axios, but the content part of the meta is empty. I use both of these techniques but the result is the same. title and description comes with axios correctly I tried the meta tags section in the Nuxtjs 3 library and looked at a few threads on stackoverflow but I didn't see a problem like mine

```
1. <template>
  <Head>
    <Title>{{getTitle}}</Title>
    <Meta name="description" :content="descripton"/>
  </Head>
  <Loading v-if="loading"></Loading>
  <product-detail v-else :id="$route.params.id"/>

</template>

<script>

import appAxios from "~/axios";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      descripton: '',
        getTitle: '',
        loading: true
    }
  },
  created() {
  this.getApp();
    },
  methods:{
    async getApp() {
      try {
        const route = useRoute();
        const response = await appAxios.get("/getProductDetail?product_id=" + route.params.id);
        this.descripton = response.data.seo.description;
        this.getTitle = response.data.seo.title;
        this.loading = false;
        console.log("response", response.data.seo);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Bir hata oluştu:", error);

      }
    }
  },

}

</script>
2. <script setup>
import appAxios from "~/axios";

const route = useRoute();
const loading = ref(true);
const title = ref('My App')
const description = ref('')

onMounted(() => {
  appAxios.get("/getProductDetail?product_id=" + route.params.id)
      .then((response) => {
        description.value = response.data.seo.description;
        title.value = response.data.seo.title;
        loading.value = false;
        console.log("MetaTag", description.value);
        console.log("response", response.data.seo.description)
      });
});
useHead({
  title,
  meta: [{
    name: 'description',
    content: description
  }]
})

</script>
```